# MSSQL drivers not found when dockerizing TeamCity

Tags: sql-server, docker, jdbc, teamcity

After I loaded one TeamCity image using this command:

```
docker run -it --name teamcity -p 8111:8111 jetbrains/teamcity-server
```

I can't get further than to the database collection when choosing MSSQL.
[image]

I tried to find a solution in the documentation and I found this page:

[Setting up TeamCity with MS SQL Server](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Setting+up+TeamCity+with+MS+SQL+Server)

I did what the documentation suggest, I downloaded the [Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55539) and I copied its content-it's a zip- in the `<Team City Data Directory>/lib/jdbc` directory.Apparently, even if I place the jar file containing the driver into the request directory, it is not recognized. I tried first copying the  `mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar` and `mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre7.jar` files in the directory an later all the content that has the zip.After that I downloaded Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 thinking it could be a version problem because the documentation suggest to copy `sqljdbc42.jar`, I also did that and nothing. Maybe is because my MSSQL server is also a docker container, and don't have some specific driver that is required to be installed in my machine.

Comment: Have you tried getting it working outside of Docker first?

Comment: @DavidG, I don't understand well the question, are you suggesting  I should install teamcity outside of Docker?

Comment: Yes, to see if it's working without the complication of Docker.

Comment: No really, I was trying to avoid that. I have other server apps running and I don't want to overload the resources. I have done this before in a machine with MSSQL server and TeamCity never showed me this kind of message. If I don't find an answer soon I will try to install it as you suggest.

Comment: You don't have a disposable Linux box or VM you can play with? That's where I would start. Ensure I can get it running before touching Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, you need to find where docker set the [TeamCity Data Directory](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/TeamCity+Data+Directory). In my case I did not specify path in the command I ran:

```
docker run -it --name teamcity-server -v C:/ProgramData/JetBrains/TeamCity -v C:/TeamCity/logs -p 8111:8111 jetbrains/teamcity-server:latest-nanoserver
```

That's why docker create a default path for me:

[image]

Once I found that path it was easy to move the .jar libraries where is necessary according to this [link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Setting+up+an+External+Database#SettingupanExternalDatabase-settingUpMSSQLMicrosoftSQLServer), which is `TeamCity Data Directory/lib/jdbc` directory

In case you want to avoid the ugly default directory you will need to specify the path for the TeamCity Data Directory in the [command](https://hub.docker.com/r/jetbrains/teamcity-server/):

```
docker run -it --name teamcity-server-instance
    -v <path to data directory>:C:/ProgramData/JetBrains/TeamCity
    -v <path to logs directory>:C:/TeamCity/logs
    -p <port on host>:8111
    jetbrains/teamcity-server:latest-nanoserver
```

where

- **path to data directory** is the host machine directory to serve as
  TeamCity Data Directory where TeamCity stores project settings and
  build results. Pass empty directory for the brand new start. When the
  mapping is not set, you will lose all the TeamCity settings on
  container shutdown.
- **path to logs directory** is the host machine directory to store
  TeamCity server logs. The mapping can be omitted, but then the logs
  will be lost on container shutdown which will make issues
  investigation impossible.

So I strongly suggest to set that field in the command because as the documentation pointed out if you don't set that field you will lose all the TeamCity settings on container shutdown.